# MSTest fails when I do run all, but works otherwise

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, mstest, rollback

So I have a Testclass using MSTest and every test works great if I run them one and one, however if I select 2 tests, namely can_register and cannot_Register_existing_username then the second fails (cannot_register_existing_username).

I have let my testclass inherit from an abstract class that looks like this:

```
public abstract class RollbackCapabilities

{

private TransactionScope _transactionScope;

    [TestInitialize]
    public virtual void TestInitialize()
    {
        _transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, new TransactionOptions { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0) });
    }


    [TestCleanup]
    public virtual void TestCleanup()
    {
        Transaction.Current.Rollback();
        _transactionScope.Dispose();
    }

}
```

If I comment this file out then it works (but now the data remains in the test-db which I don't want).

With this file above active the second test fails, the tests look like this

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Can_Register()
    {
        //Arrange
        AccountController ac = ControllerFactory.CreateAccountController();
        RegisterModel model = new RegisterModel();
        model.UserName = "TestUser";
        model.Password= "TestPassword";
        model.ConfirmPassword = "TestPassword";

        //Act
        ActionResult result = ac.Register(model);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(RedirectToRouteResult));
        Assert.AreEqual("Home", ((RedirectToRouteResult)result).RouteValues["controller"]);
        Assert.AreEqual("Index", ((RedirectToRouteResult)result).RouteValues["action"]);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Cannot_Register_Existing_Username()
    {
        //Arrange
        AccountController ac = ControllerFactory.CreateAccountController();
        RegisterModel model = new RegisterModel();
        model.UserName = "TestUser";
        model.Password = "TestPassword";
        model.ConfirmPassword = "TestPassword";
        ac.Register(model);
        RegisterModel model2 = new RegisterModel();
        model2.UserName = "TestUser";
        model2.Password = "OtherTestPassword";
        model2.ConfirmPassword = "OtherTestPassword";

        //Act
        ActionResult result = ac.Register(model2);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ViewResult));
        Assert.AreEqual("", ((ViewResult)result).ViewName);
        Assert.AreEqual(model2, ((ViewResult)result).ViewData.Model);
    }
```

and finally the error i get is as follows:

> Test method
>   Viducate.UnitTests.UserHandling.RegisterTests.Cannot_Register_Existing_Username
>   threw exception:  System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An
>   error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.Users'.

Thats my problem, not big but very annoying and as mentioned if I run the tests one and one it works, it also works but leaves data in the db if I comment out my RollbackCapabilities class

Comment: Are you sure that your TestInitialize and TestCleanup methods are executed that way?

Comment: Are you sure that `Transaction.Current.Rollback();` is executing as you expect? Try putting a break point on that line and debug the tests and see if it is.

Comment: Things are being called in right order First intilialize, then test1, then cleanup, then initialize, then test2 then crash

Comment: And when it comes to what Rollback does, well to be honest I right now don't know how to check if it did the right thing or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found out that my error was that I had created the database (but not tables) by hand because create database is not supported in multi-transaction.

however creating an empty database means that EF assumes there is tables already and that is why it failed with dont know what dbo.users are.

So what I did was created the tables as well and now it works. However this means I can never run this on a new development machine without first creating the tables and database. so annoying.

I think I will set up another test class that does not inherit my abstract rollback class and hade that create the tables permanently... should solve the problem as long as that runs first.

Comment: You can set up the environment using the AssemblyInitialize attribute.